# Wallaby is failing when converting FLA with actionscript into HTML5 format

Tags: html, flash-cs5

Adobe has offered a beta called [Wallaby](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/wallaby/) to convert Flash files in .fla format into HTML5 format. The problem is that we have some files we have coded some ActionScript, and this converter is firing an error telling that cannot be converted.

I don't know if any of you has similar issues and what can be done to avoid this type of errors? Should we remove all action script or try to convert this using another tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try another tool if one exists.  But Wallaby currently only is for FLA files without any ActionScript. I think at most you can have a stop(); action.  Sorry man.